# AssemblyLoad event is not fired in AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DefaultAppDomainApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("***** Fun with the default app domain *****\n");
            InitDAD();

            DisplayDADStats();
            Console.WriteLine();

            ListAllAssembliesInAppDomain();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        #region Init the default app domain
        private static void InitDAD()
        {
            // This logic will print out the name of any assembly
            // loaded into the applicaion domain, after it has been
            // created. 
            AppDomain defaultAD = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            defaultAD.AssemblyLoad += (o, s) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} has been loaded!", s.LoadedAssembly.GetName().Name);
                };
        }
        #endregion

        #region Display basic stats
        private static void DisplayDADStats()
        {
            // Get access to the app domain for the current thread.
            AppDomain defaultAD = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

            Console.WriteLine("Name of this domain: {0}", defaultAD.FriendlyName);
            Console.WriteLine("ID of domain in this process: {0}", defaultAD.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Is this the default domain?: {0}", defaultAD.IsDefaultAppDomain());
            Console.WriteLine("Base directory of this domain: {0}", defaultAD.BaseDirectory);
        } 
        #endregion

        #region List loaded assemblies 
        static void ListAllAssembliesInAppDomain()
        {
            // Get access to the app domain for the current thread.
            AppDomain defaultAD = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

            // Now get all loaded assemblies in the default app domain. 
            var loadedAssemblies = from a in defaultAD.GetAssemblies() orderby a.GetName().Name select a;

            Console.WriteLine("***** Here are the assemblies loaded in {0} *****\n",
              defaultAD.FriendlyName);
            foreach (var a in loadedAssemblies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-> Name: {0}", a.GetName().Name);
                Console.WriteLine("-> Version: {0}\n", a.GetName().Version);
            }
        } 
        #endregion

    }
}
```

The above code I got from "Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform" book by 'Andrew Troelsen'.
Here when I run this code, the control never reaches the line

```
defaultAD.AssemblyLoad += (o, s) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has been loaded!", s.LoadedAssembly.GetName().Name);
};
```

Why this event is not fired when I run this code? When the control reaches here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (and what I have experienced), the event only fires when one of the `Assembly.Load` methods are used.

It will not fire when the runtime resolves and loads an assembly automatically.

Comment: Where do the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload(v=vs.110).aspx) say that? At least the current version just says "Occurs when an assembly is loaded."

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The correct answer is found below - you are adding the event handler too late to catch anything.

Answer (score 2):

This event handler is not reached for several reasons.  The AppDomain.CurrentDomain has loaded all the assemblies it needs to begin executing your Main method.  So you are adding your event handler too late.  You need to add a special static method that .NET framework looks for and will execute to run your app init code, it is called AppInitialize and you would bind your handler there.  Do some digging on AppInitialize.

Also your domain is not the only domain involved.  There is definitely at least one other shared app domain where all the GAC and Fully trusted assemblies get loaded into.  Plus there could be other app domains based on how the application is configured and how other assemblies load their dependencies.  Perform your due diligent research on MSDN on the topic of Application Domains.

Answer (score 1):

Event doesn't fire because when application starts the all referenced assemblies are already loaded (in case when you haven't dynamically load assemblies).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing issues with AssemblyLoad. I had to investigate it with the following setup:

1. During an ASP.Net application start up, at the point of configuring DI, an event handler was added to AssemblyLoad event logging all loaded assemblies and the AppDomain FirendlyName.
2. After that all already loaded assemblies were also logged.
3. At a controller constructor elsewhere all loaded assemblies were logged again.
4. All dependencies were in GAC.

Results:
All logs showed the same AppDomain name, but the controller logs showed more loaded assemblies than those logged initially by (2) and by AssemblyLoad event handler (1) combined. So it did not look like the AssemblyLoad even was fired for all loaded assemblies.